# Document insert with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Here's my Mongoose schema:

```
var DealSchema = new Schema({
    deal:{
        dealid:{
            type: String,
            require: true,
            unique: true,
        },
        title: String,
    },

    // Embedded sub-document
    details: {
        detail: String,
        price: Number   // USE: deal.details.price
    }
})
```

My insert statement is as follows:

```
db.deals.insert({
    deal.dealid: '1',
    deal.title: 'deal',

    details.detail: 'Free Food',
    details.price: 200
})
```

The error I am getting:

```
SyntaxError: missing : after property id @(shell):2:4
```

Not sure what this error means - how can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your object syntax in the insert is incorrect - it needs to be proper JSON, unless you use dot notation as @krl explained.

Assuming you're using Mongoose:

```
db.deals.insert({
    deal: {
        dealid: '1',
        title: 'deal'
    },
    details: {
        detail: 'Free Food',
        price: 200
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I learnt both the methods. The correct json way and the embedded document with dot(.) method.

Answer (score 3):

To specify or access a field of an embedded document with dot notation, concatenate the embedded document name with the dot (.) and the field name, and enclose in quotes (both single and double quotes are acceptable) (see [Documents > Dot Notation > Embedded Documents](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#embedded-documents)):

```
db.deals.insert({
    'deal.dealid': '1',
    'deal.title': 'deal',

    'details.detail': 'Free Food',
    'details.price': 200
})
```

Answer (score 1):

JSON format in that call is invalid. Try this:

```
db.deals.insert({
    deal: {
           dealid: '1',
           title: 'deal'
    },

    details: {
           detail: 'Free Food',
           price: 200
    }
});
```